# HTML code working in r leaflet for popups but not for labels

Tags: html, r, leaflet

So I'm working with leaflet in R Studio and I'm trying to include some HTML code into the popups and labels of the icons.
I just can't figure out why it's working for the popups but not the labels.

Here's my code:

```
library(leaflet)

library(htmlwidgets)

library(htmltools)

leaflet(MerchCoOrds) %>% addTiles() %>%
addCircleMarkers(data=MerchCoOrds, lng=~MerchLongitude, lat=~MerchLatitude, col = ~pal(MerchCoOrds$merchant_state), 
                 stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1.0, 
                 popup=~paste("<h3 >Merchant ID:</h3>",MerchCoOrds$merchant_id, "<h3 >Transaction ID:</h3>", 
                              MerchCoOrds$transaction_id, sep=" "), 
                 label=paste(htmltools::HTML("<h3 >Merchant State:</h3>"), MerchCoOrds$merchant_state, 
                             htmltools::HTML("<h3 >Merchant Suburb:</h3>"), MerchCoOrds$merchant_suburb, sep=" ")) %>%
addLegend(pal=pal,values =~MerchCoOrds$merchant_state, opacity=1, title="State of Transaction",
          position="bottomright") %>%
  addControl(title, position="topright")
```

I've tried it both by starting the line with `htmltools::HTML` and by doing it the same way I did it for the popups (just using the paste function) and neither work for the labels.
When I run the code and hover over the icons it comes up with Merchant State: before correctly pasting the merchant state name and then it says Merchant Suburb: before correctly pasting the merchant suburb.

I'm wondering if perhaps labels don't support HTML for whatever reason.

Also just as a quick note I put a space in all the  code so it didn't automatically convert to HTML in this post.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to format code.

Answer (score 2):

Ok sorry everyone.

I found a solution in section 3.5 here:
https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/307862_b8c8460272dc4a2a9023d033d5f3ec34.html

I'm going to leave the post up in case someone else runs into this problem.

Here is the final code that works as I intended
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2ihR.png)